# How to link to any tab of coda slider from another page

Tags: hyperlink, tabs, slider, coda

I am having trouble linking directly to a tab of coda slider from another page.
The site of [Coda Slider](http://kevinbatdorf.github.com/codaslider/) tells how to link to any tab from the same page. like this

`<a href="#3" data-ref="slider-id">Tab 3</a>`   (#3 for 3rd tab)

but there's no info for linking from another page .

my slider page is index.html and another page in the same folder is abc.html .

I tried `<a href="index.html#3" data-ref="slider-id">Tab 3</a>` but it didn't work.

Please help.